# SAPUI5 - navigation - Binding not working

Tags: sapui5

Demo - http://jsbin.com/bukanagobu/1/edit

The problem is when i click on one of the item, it navigates to the next view but it is not displaying the firstname and lastname.

I have saved the model as 'data'.

Can anyone help me in finding the error ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getBindingContext() Returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913868/getbindingcontext-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made two mistakes in your code:

- When getting the binding context upon clicking an entry in the list, you must specify the named model name 'data':

  ```js
  var oBindingContext = evt.getSource().getBindingContext("data"); 
  // if using named models, specify which model you want to use
  ```
- Also, when setting the binding context to the detail view, you must also set the model name to 'data':

  ```js
  page2.setBindingContext(oBindingContext, "data"); 
  // also, name the context model to 'data'
  ```

See the updated JSBin here : http://jsbin.com/fehoqu/1/edit?html,output