# getBindingContext() returns undefined

Tags: sapui5

I am working on a SplitApp. On selecting an item from the list, it says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPath' of undefined

#### Master.controller.js

```js
onSelect: function(oEvent) {
  this.showDetail(oEvent.getParameter("listItem") || oEvent.getSource());
},

showDetail: function(oItem) {
  // ...
  this.getRouter().navTo("detail", {
    from: "master",
    entity: oItem.getBindingContext().getPath().substr(1), // Error
    tab: this.sTab
  }, bReplace);
},
```

`oItem.getBindingContext()` returns `undefined`. So I believe the problem is with binding context.

#### Master.view.xml

```xml
<List id="list" growing="true" items="{data>/results}">
  <ObjectListItem id="listItem"
    title="{myModel>PROJECTNAME}"
    number="{myModel>REVENUE}"
    numberUnit="{myModel>CURRENCY}"
    press=".onSelect"
  />
</List>
```

#### Component.js

```js
// JSONModel required from "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
var oModel= new JSONModel();
oModel.loadData("Data.json");
this.setModel(oModel,"myModel");
```

The list is displayed but when I select the item, the error is thrown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the binding context of clicked item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556515/how-to-get-the-binding-context-of-clicked-item)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> #### [`getBindingContext(sModelName?)`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/getBindingContext)
>
> *Get the binding context of this object for the given model name. If the object does not have a binding context set on itself and has no own Model set, it will use the first binding context defined in its parent hierarchy.*

You have given name to the model (`this.setModel(oModel, "myModel")`).
Specify the model name (`oItem.getBindingContext("myModel")`) to access the binding context.

The same applies to `setBindingContext(oContext, "myModel")`.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```js
oItem.getBindingContext("myModel").getPath().substr(1)
```

You have to **pass the name of the model** to `getBindingContext`, if the bound model has been named.