# onPress-Event in SmartTables

Tags: sapui5

In a normal list we have sth like this

```
<List noDataText="---" id="__list0" items="{model>/Orders}">
    <items>
        <StandardListItem type="Navigation" title="{model>OrderName}" press="onPress" />
    </items>
</List>
```

So we set the press-Event in the Items, but if we have a SmartTable we do not have the inner

```
<StandardListItem type="Navigation" title="{model>OrderName}" press="onPress" />
```

I just have:

```
<sap.ui.comp.smarttable:SmartTable xmlns:sap.ui.comp.smarttable="sap.ui.comp.smarttable"
height="100%" 
width="100%" 
direction="Column" 
fitContainer="true" 
tableType="ResponsiveTable" 
header="Smart Table" 
enableAutoBinding="true" 
id="__table0" 
entitySet="Datas"/>
```

//Not the same Model in this case

How can I set an onPress event for the columns?

Thank you very much for your Help.

Comment: Please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829620/smart-table-onclick-event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smart Table, onclick event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829620/smart-table-onclick-event)